# Django and loading config file before server starts

Tags: django

My django app is communicating with external server and before running django server i would like load some config file. Variables from this file are going to be used by some module while app is running
Problem is that config file can be located in many places.

My dream would be to run `manage.py --cfg "/path/to/cfg/file.cfg"` or
`manage.py runserver --cfg "/path/to/cfg/file.cfg"`
and  some variables (like globals?) are going to be loaded and they are going to be avaible for django modules to be used. After django server shutdown those variables can dissapear

Is there some nice way to accomplish this?

Comment: are you planning on using the runserver for production (which is discouraged for "real" production but which is a perfectly fine thing for something private) or eventually migrate to WSGI or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two parts to your problem:

1. How do I support changing which set of variables (as defined in a config file) are used for a given run
2. How can I load these variables such that they are visible to all the modules of my application.

The standard mechanism for doing the 2nd is to put stuff in settings.py.
If you do `FOO="bar"` in settings.py, in your module you can do:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.FOO == "bar":
    # Do something
```

As far as how you can support multiple configurations, the first thing I could come up with is to rename your real settings.py to be real_settings.py and then create a series of config1_settings.py, config2_settings.py, config3_settings.py ... which look like:

```
from real_settings.py import *
from path_to_configX.py import *
```

where configX.py has all the values for whatever variables you want for configuration X.

You would then start django's built in server via:
`manage.py runserver --settings=configX_settings.py`

Note that doing this for a production server (where you can't as easily just pass something on the command line to kick it off) may be a bit trickier, but you're going to need to provide more use case details for that.

Comment: It's nice solution. I have no idea how it would look like on production - it's our first bigger project :) Thanks for you answer Foon